# Deixar um elemento hide(escondido) com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um elemento com o ID="not1" que é um link para títulos de noticias inseridos sendo criados dinamicamente  com as noticias respectivas de cada título class=" col-md-12" como mostro abaixo.

```
<div id="noticia">
     <div id="not1"><a href="<?php $noticia['idp_postjauport'] ?>"><?php print $noticia['tit_postjauport'] ?></a></div>
     <div class="col-md-12" id="col-md-12">
     <?php print $noticia['pos_postjauport'] ?>
     </div>

     </div> 
     </p>
```

tenho um javascript que deveria mostrar o conteúdo do meu link somente quando eu clicar nele, javascript abaixo.

```
    <script type="text/jscript">

$("#not1").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      $("#col-md-12").hide('slow');

      $("#col-md-12").show(3000);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});

    </script>
```

O que esta ocorrendo é que minha pagina html esta trazendo esse elemento aberto, mas se eu clicar no link ele fecha e abre novamente...não sei como corrigir esse pequeno problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deves ter CSS que esconda esse link. Assim ele está escondido no momento em que é criado.

Podes ter o CSS no ficheiro `.css` da página

```
#col-md-12 {display: none;}
```

ou inline no momento da criação do link. Se criares o link com JavaScript é só fazer `el.style.display = 'none';` **antes** de ele ser inserido no DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar no javascript uma instrução para ocultar o conteúdo do link assim que a página iniciar. Como você está utilizando jQuery, isso pode ser feito com a seguinte função:

```
$(document).ready({
   $("#col-md-12").hide();
});
```